# Suddenly webview behaviour changed to erase stored cookie and php session variables

Tags: php, android, session, cookies, webview

I've searched many posts, tried dozens code changes and stripped my code down to webview only, but can't figure out this problem. I made an app before where it works fine to continue using one PHP Session or/and cookie I've set inside the webview. I used [AdvancedWebView](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView) and now [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/). The behaviour is the same on this new app I'm developing.

So this is how I create the webview and load content using my `onCreate` method (MainActivity):

```
        mWebView = (XWalkView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JS_Bind(this, mWebView), "Android");
        mWebView.load("http://example.com/index.php?page=home", null);
```

If I'm using `<a href="?page=test">Link</a>` inside the webview the `$_SESSION` variables are still stored, but if there's another `mWebView.load` and I click on it, all `$_SESSION` (and `$_COOKIE`) data is erased.

The only things I can think of that are different to my previous app (where it worked as I mentioned), is using a newer google-playservices and gradle version.

Also worth to mention is that I have a fragment class (Cards) that is the only class not extending my MainActivity. And there I'm having a sort of to-do-list where users can check and uncheck cards they've found. This creates a cookie to store this data using Javascript. This data won't get erased on new page loads.
So I thought there must be an error in the MainActivity class, but like I said, I stripped it down to the webview only.

I also tried adding methods that enables cookie getting saved, but this doesn't change anything. So I thought it could also be a php problem. Then however it works fine in browsers when I'm loading the url on my PC (and chrome browser on my Android device also) but not using my app.

**What possibilities could cause that behaviour not storing sessions?**

Edit: I can show the url to my app, maybe this makes it more clear: [www.vaydesign.com/tw3/](http://www.vaydesign.com/tw3/)
And the app in the Play Store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vaydesign.thewitcher3

Edit 2: I added a video to demonstrate what I mean. Note the $_SESSION output text at the bottom when I scroll down the menu before and after changing the language (where `mWebView.load` is called`):

https://picload.org/image/rrrrgrgd/ezgif.com-video-to-gif.gif

Edit 3: I noticed one strange behaviour. If you register a new account and login, you'll see different cookie variables are set (scroll to the bottom of the page). If you change the orientation to reload the page you'll see your old cookies again (if you selected some items in the "Cards" section). So it seems like I'm on an whole other domain (or thread?) directly after the login and if you reload the page, you see the old cookies again (but only those saved via Javascript). Nevertheless PHP session aren't saved at all as it seems. Note: The first array shown at the bottom of each page is the `$_SESSION` array, then comes the `$_COOKIE` array.